# Parllax-like plugin needed, jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, parallax

Is anybody aware of a plugin which can be used to create something like the following?

http://www.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/10/27/south-china-sea/

In fact it makes the element "position:fixed" when the top of the element reaches the top of the page and then scrolls the contents. However I'm not sure if there's a ready plugin for such functionality.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at one of the following plugins, might be what you need. (I've included links to demos.)

- [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) - [(demo)](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/)
- [scrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/) - [(demo)](http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/)
- [superscrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/) - [(demo)](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/)

They all support "pinning" an element to the top while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Sequence.js is close to what you are looking for. http://www.sequencejs.com/

He has a pretty close demo here: http://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/

---

edit: here is another I had bookmarked: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr (demo: http://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/parallax-scroll-effect/)